# showing HTML in field instructions, not rendering?

Tags: expressionengine

I have a field for embedding videos. In the description I would like to show a sample of what that code should look like. However natively EE will render the HTML. Is there a way to show exactly what the code should look like without it being rendered? Other fields have HTML that needs to render so if there is a global on/off it must be on.

Comment: %3Ciframe%3E does not work if you are thinking that is the answer.

Comment: Simple solution would be to just use `&lt;` and `&gt;` to escape `<` and `>` signs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy and paste your code into this Encoder and paste the output into the description field:

http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/HTMLEncode/encode.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [NSM Publish Hints](http://ee-garage.com/nsm-publish-hints)

Comment: Thanks, the comment above shows how to show HTML in the instructions (&gt; and &lt;). This is also a really good idea for this channel. It will be used by people who are not necessarily very technical.

Answer (score 4):

If we are talking about a specific CF in a channel, the way I go about it is as follow:

- For external services (youtube/viemo): have a custom field (text) where people just have to paste in the ID of the video, and another field (P&T pill or dropwown) where editors choose the service (vimeo, youtube). The various embed codes are handled on the template side within an if/else or case logic
- For HTML5 self hosted videos: have several file fields letting people choose videos in the various needed formats. These videos are uploaded through FTP and synced using the file manager.

Comment: I was asking about the instructions, ie how to show the proper embed code and not have it render. 

However your tip is a good one that would keep users from needing to mess with embed code. However they would need to get the video ID. How user friendly have you found that to be?

Comment: There are also several add-ons to help the user easily pick, choose and add. Some are on my 'to-check-out list) http://www.devdemon.com/channel_videos/ and http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/antenna

Comment: Wrote clear instructions as to where the video ID is in the URL of a video on vimeo and showed client during training, never had an issue so far. That being said, if you fear that your users will not be savvy enough, the add-ons GDmac pointed you too would be a better fit.